# Completing a metric space where only (eventually) positive, negative or zero sequences converge.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ define $d'(x, y)$ by

$d'(x, y) =  \begin{cases} 
      |x - y|+1 & if \space exactly \space one \space among \space x\space and\space y\space is\space (strictly)\space positive.\\
      |x - y| & otherwise \\
   \end{cases}
$

Show that the metric space is incomplete and complete.

I noticed that if a sequence is (eventually) negative, positive or zero, then $d$ is the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, the sequence converges. If the sequence is say, $(\frac{1}{n})$ which converges to $0$, then it does not converge under this new metric.

My attempt a completion under this new metric was to let $X' = X \space\cup\space{+0}$ where $+0$ has the following properties:

$d(x, +0) =  \begin{cases} 
      |x| & if \space x \space \neq 0.\\
      +0 & if\space x=0 \\
   \end{cases}
$

So, now the aforementioned series $(\frac{1}{n})$ converges to $+0$. But then I considered, $\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$, the subsequence of the negative terms, converge to $0$ and the subsequence of positive terms converge to $+0$.

I thought it was still convergent despite, $+0 \neq 0$ implying there exists $\epsilon_{0}$ such that $d(+0, 0) = \epsilon_{0}$. However, consider $d(+0, 0) \leq d(\frac{\epsilon_{0}}{4},+0) + d(\frac{\epsilon_{0}}{4},0) = \frac{\epsilon_{0}}{2} < \epsilon_{0}$.

I don't understand how to approach completing this metric space. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A very loose hint: you say that $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ has two subsequences that converge, and you say that you thought the sequence was convergent overall. Does the distance between consecutive terms go to zero? The real problem with your $+0$ definition (and specifically the distance you've defined) is that the sequence $-(\frac1n)$ converges to both zero and plus-zero with the metric you give.

Comment: Under this new metric? No. Because in any pair of consecutive terms, exactly one is positive. So, the distance go to 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z=(-\infty,0] \cup (1,\infty)$ with the usual metric $|z-w|$ induced from ${\mathbb R}$.  The function $F: {\mathbb R}  \to Z$ defined by $F(x)=x$ for $x \le 0$ and $F(x)=x+1$ for $x>0$, is an isometry from  $ ({\mathbb R},d')$ onto  $(Z, |\cdot-\cdot|)$.
Since it is clear how to complete $Z$ by adding $1$, this  tells us how to complete $({\mathbb R},d') $: Add a point $*$, with $d'(*,x)=1+|x|$ for $x\le0$ and $d'(*,x)= |x|$ for $x>0$.

The resulting metric space $ ({\mathbb R}\cup \{*\},d')$  is complete. Indeed, it is isometric to the completion of $Z$, namely to $(-\infty,0] \cup [1,\infty)$ with the usual metric. (The isometry is the obvious extension of $F$.)

Comment: Ok. I understand how it is clear adding 1 to $Z$ completes it. However, I'm having trouble understanding how the point * completes $(\mathbb{R}, d).$

Comment: Check that the resulting metric space is complete. Indeed, it is isometric to $(-\infty,0 \cup [1,\infty)$ with the usual metric.

Comment: Ahh I understand now thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to accept an answer?